# How to get actual User Agent in MFP 8 cordova application(Android/iOS)

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, firewall, user-agent, okhttp

```
Environment Details:
   1. CLI version-7.0.0,
   2. OKHTTP Version-2.0.0,
   3. Cordova-plugin-mfp Version-8.0.2017100610,
   4. Cordova-plugin-mfp-push Version-8.0.2017112208,
   5. Cordova-Android - ~6.3.0,
   6. Cordova-iOS - ^4.4.0
```

**Problem:**
Android and iPhone Application is built using above version. We have a firewall which intercepts the request to recognize whether the request originated from Mobile.

Firewall check is made based on User-agent, for adapter calls, We receive user-agent as **"OK http/3.4.1"**. So firewall rejects the request.

But ***MFP API call /context/api/az/v1/token*** has user agent of ***WLNativeplugin(One plus Android).***

What is the ideal way of getting the Actual **User-agent** from Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

The User-Agent string can be different depending on the origin of the request - this could be from the Javascript layer or the native SDK layer. You should consider adding a rule to the firewall to allow both the User-Agent strings you have noted.

Comment: In earlier versions of MFP, we used to trigger the adapter from the Javascript layer and it work's well in the same environment. Also, OkHttp cannot be considered as Mobile device originator where any endpoint can trigger. So how can we make ensure that Mobile app triggers the request.

Comment: okhttp starts with MFP 8.0 only. The MFP SDK makes use of okhttp as networking library

Comment: Security team doesn't accept okhttp as valid user-agent. As it has to take mobile user agent. What is the alternate?